# How to sort the month in Map Hashmap Java

Tags: java

I got trouble when put month as key on Java hashmap.
Can someone help me?

I want to display :
{January=0.0, February=0.0, March=0.0, April=0.0}

But, the result from the code is :
{March=0.0, January=0.0, February=0.0, April=0.0}

This is my code..

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Double> capitalCities = new HashMap<String,Double>();
    capitalCities.put("January", 0.0);
    capitalCities.put("February", 0.0);
    capitalCities.put("March", 0.0);
    capitalCities.put("April", 0.0);
    System.out.println(capitalCities); 
  }
}
```

I'm so struggling about it, please help

Comment: Use `LinkedHashMap` to preserve the key order.

Comment: By the way, Java may be getting a new **“sequenced” collections interfaces**. See a brief preview introduction in yet another good [video by Nicolai Parlog](https://youtu.be/xBBuShS0ERs?t=91) on YouTube.

Answer (score 6):

There are two problems with your approach, as far as I can see.

The first is that a `HashMap` doesn't sort its entries in any particular order.  It's not specified which order the entries will appear in, if you iterate through the `Map`.

To overcome this, you should use a different kind of `Map`.  A [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) should fit your requirement, as it stores its entries in order.

The second problem is that by default, `String` values will be sorted alphabetically, but you actually want to sort the months in calendar order.  You can get around this by using the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enumeration in the `java.time` package, as the key for your `Map`.

If you fix both these issues, the code will look something like this.

```
Map<Month,Double> capitalCities = new TreeMap<>();
capitalCities.put(Month.JANUARY, 0.0);
capitalCities.put(Month.FEBRUARY, 0.0);
```

and so on.

**Addendum:** Alexander Ivanchenko's solution using `EnumMap` is better than this one.

Comment: Another approach is to use a `LinkedHashMap` and rely on inserting the months in order. Then the original code works as is.

Comment: @tgdavies You could post your own answer.

Comment: @BasilBourque I prefer my original wording.  Do you mind if I undo your edit?

Comment: Do as you feel best. I do recommend making some mention of`NavigableMap`.  And I added more edits, linking to Javadoc. Perhaps you could add another edit rather than rollback.

Answer (score 4):

As *@Dawood ibn Kareem* has pointed out in [*his answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73495550/17949945) enum `Month` from `java.time` package is better option than using a plain `String`.

I want to add that since Java 5 we have a special purpose implementation of the `Map` interface - [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html), which maintain its entries sorted according to the natural order of `enum` used as a *key*.

Here's an example:

```
Map<Month, Double> valueByMonth = new EnumMap<>(Month.class);
valueByMonth.put(Month.JULY, 9.3);
valueByMonth.put(Month.APRIL, 4.8);
valueByMonth.put(Month.FEBRUARY, 3.9);
valueByMonth.put(Month.JANUARY, 1.0);
valueByMonth.put(Month.MARCH, 4.5);
        
valueByMonth.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v)); // printing map's contents
```

*Output:*

```
JANUARY -> 1.0
FEBRUARY -> 3.9
MARCH -> 4.5
APRIL -> 4.8
JULY -> 9.3
```

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know about `EnumMap` until now.  This solution is better than mine.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem There's also a specialized version of `Set` - [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html#method-summary), sometimes it might be handy. It's `allOf()` method can be used as a substitution of `values()`, and there are few more interesting methods like `range()`, which creates a set of enum-members that are within the range of two specified elements.